# Changing animation's center and angle

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

Is it possible to set a new center and an angle to an animation?
I'm trying to build an animation to curl a page but just partially but by default this effect curls the page from bottom right to upside left.
Here is a chunk of the code I'm using to animate this.

```
- (IBAction)curlUp{
// Curl the image up or down
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
[animation setDelegate:self];
[animation setDuration:0.35];
[animation setTimingFunction:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

if (!curled){
    animation.type = @"pageCurl";
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    animation.endProgress = 0.78;
} else {
    animation.type = @"pageUnCurl";
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeBackwards;
    animation.startProgress = 0.42;
}
[animation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
[[self view] exchangeSubviewAtIndex:4 withSubviewAtIndex:5];

[[[self view] layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"pageCurlAnimation"];

// Disable user interaction where necessary
if (curled) {
    [[self view] exchangeSubviewAtIndex:4 withSubviewAtIndex:5];
    [[[[self view] subviews] lastObject] removeFromSuperview];
    } else {[self.view addSubview:ofertasCompraViewController.view];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.view];
    //[self.navigationController.navigationBar setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    //[self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
}
curled = !curled;
}
```

The end progress sets where the page will stop curling and now I would like to set in which direction the view will curl.

Thanx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a solution to my problem a couple of days after asking in here. I'm going to post the code I used so that anybody can check it. Maybe it will be useful for somebody else!

```
// Curl the image up or down
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
[animation setDelegate:self];
[animation setDuration:0.35];
[animation setTimingFunction:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

if (!curled){
    animation.type = @"pageCurl";
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    animation.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;
    animation.endProgress =0.75;
} else {
    animation.type = @"pageUnCurl";
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeBackwards;
    animation.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;
    animation.startProgress = 0.42;
}
[animation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
if(cambioVista)
[[self view] exchangeSubviewAtIndex:4 withSubviewAtIndex:5];

[[[self view] layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"pageCurlAnimation"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't help you with this but I've seen a number of threads on this type of animation, and apple is keen to reject apps that are using this code as they are 'using private APIs'. See this [thread](https://discussions.apple.com/message/8371847?messageID=8371847) on the apple forums.